# UIRefreshControl only shows when view is presented for the first time

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a vertical scroll view which takes up the full view. I've added a UIRefreshControl to the scroll view and it all works great... Until the view is dismissed and then presented again. When it's presented again, the UIRefreshControl just doesn't exist anymore. I've tried using the `scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)` method within `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, and `viewWillAppear`. Each resulting in the same issue. Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT:
I've also used: `scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

Comment: You'll need to provide some more detail about what you're doing. You mention: *"Until the view is dismissed and then presented again"* ... are you **presenting** a view controller? Is your scroll view a subview the you are showing / hiding? Are you pushing to the controller in a navigation controller? A simple test: presenting a view controller that has a scroll view, and the refresh control is set in `viewDidLoad()`... and I'm not seeing any issues.

Comment: @DonMag The view controller containing the scroll view is presented modally, full screen. It can be dismissed by the user. If they choose to go back into that view controller after the dismissal, the UIRefreshControl is no longer there. The scroll view is a subview of view in the presented view controller.

Comment: *"It can be dismissed by the user"* ... So, you have a button or something in the scroll view content that dismisses it? As I said, I did a quick test and have no problem getting the refresh control every time I present / dismiss / present / dismiss / present my controller. You may need to provide a [mre] to get help.

Comment: Just finished coding a minimal example and it works how it should. I'll investigate a bit more.